# Convert XML String to XML in WCF Service C#

Tags: c#, html, wcf

I am sending a XML string in HTML back to my WCF Service C#.

```html
<script>
        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/test");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        let xml = `<?xml version='1.0'?><query><testNumber>5</testNumber></query>`;
        xmlhttp.send(xml);
</script>
```

However, I am getting a 400 bad request error from my WCF Service C#. Not sure why.

```cs
// This is my IService
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/test", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        string testXML(string testNumber);
```

```cs
// This is my service
        public string testXML(string testNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(testNumber);
                return "passed";
            } catch (System.Xml.XmlException e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString());
                return "failed";
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does your request look like (I mean the actual request that's being made, not the code that makes it)?

Comment: Do you mean "string testNumber"?

Comment: No I mean like open up your browser's debugger, head to the network tab, trigger the request, and see what the request looks like. [Docs for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/), [Docs for Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/), [Docs for Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/network/).

Comment: I checked the Payload and this is inside <?xml version='1.0'?><query><testNumber>5</testNumber></query>

Comment: 404 bad request ? Or not found ?

Comment: It's a 400 Bad Request

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and correct it (404 -> 400)

Comment: You can start by running wcf service locally to see if you can send xml. If you can, it's the issue of html.

Comment: Okay I managed to solve it by changing the parameter type in OperationContract to XElement testNumber instead of string testNumber

Comment: Is there any progress on this problem